# Where to put random functions?

Tags: functions

I have functions for setting default values when a new user signs up, functions for performance testing, functions for writing out a small icon to the admin tool bar, and so on.

These functions are scattered around where I'm using them, which is in templates, plugins, and so on. Where should I be putting them? I know there is a `theme/functions.php` and a `wp-includes/functions.php` and that seems like the logical place to put them, but my hosting company is set to upgrade my installs to the latest versions. I don't want my code in the `functions.php` to be overwritten. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp-includes/functions.php` is never a file you should modify. Any mention of adding something to `functions.php` is never referring to this file.

Functions related to front-end display or theme behavior should go in your theme's `functions.php`. If the theme may potentially be updated, then you should be using a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to add functionality, and they should go in your child theme's `functions.php`. Child themes are update-safe - a core update will not overwrite a child theme.

For any code that should persist regardless of active theme, those functions should go in your own [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). Your own plugins are update-safe.

Regardless of what option you choose, you should always have a local recent backup in case you need to restore things.

Comment: OK. It sounds like I should create a plugin then. I have a few event handlers for "wpmu_new_blog". Can I put those in the plugin?

Comment: yes, those would be most appropriate in a plugin.